# How to properly update package with tlmgr (package manager for TexLive)?

Tags: overleaf, tlmgr, nicematrix

I want to update my "nicematrix" in TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) to the v5.11 one, but after I ran

```
tlmgr update --self
tlmgr update nicematrix
```

it's up-to-dated as v5.12. However, I cannot compile my files with this version, as it incadicates

```
usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x:NNn \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                   \c__nicematrix_types_of_m...
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x:NNn \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                   \c__nicematrix_types_of_m...
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x:NNn \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                   \c__nicematrix_types_of_m...
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x:NNn \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                   \c__nicematrix_types_of_m...
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x:NNn \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                   \c__nicematrix_types_of_m...
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x:NNn \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                   \c__nicematrix_types_of_m...
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x_seq \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                  
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x_seq \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                  
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x_seq \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                  
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x_seq \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                  
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x_seq \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                  
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5805: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A sequence was misused.
l.5805 ...x_seq \c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq
                                                  

/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty:5806: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbf{I}_{temp}=\begin{bNiceArray}{CCC@{\quad \quad}CCC@{\quad \quad}CCC@{\quad \quad}CCC}
    255 & 128 & 127 & 126 & 125 & 64 & 100 & 99 & 50 & 20 & 10 & 9  \\
  \end{bNiceArray}^{\intercal}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The reasons why I need to update it lie in:

1. The default **nicematrix** packge （v3.14） only supports **capital letters** in the preamble of the environments.
2. Overleaf with 2020 texlive only supports **lowercase letters** in the preamble of the environments of **nicematrix**. (The version seems to be later than v5)
3. I want both of them can complie the same files smoothly, by updating my local **nicematrix** or working with a magic workround.

Questions:

1. How to update package into a certain version with tlmgr, e.g. **nicematrix** v5.11?
2. Is this situation a bug of **nicematrix** v5.12?

Welcome any other workround!

Comment: How do you come to conclusion 1 "The default nicematrix packge only supports capital letters in the preamble of the environments."? Upper case letters were only used in versions prior to nicematrix version 5. If you whish to combine environments with lower and upper case column specifiers in one document, you can use the `define-L-C-R` package option.

Comment: See also the following quote from the `nicematrix` documentation: "Before the version 5.0, it was mandatory to use, for technical reasons, the letters `L`, `C` et `R` instead of `l`,`c` et `r` in the preambles of the environments of `nicematrix`. If we want to be able to go on using these letters, `nicematrix` must be loaded with the option `define-L-C-R.`"

Comment: Here is a corresponding MWE, that works with `nicematrix` version 5.12 and used both upper and lower case column specifiers: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[define-L-C-R]{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
text & text & text \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\begin{NiceTabular}{LCR}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
text & text & text \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved in comments

Comment: @leandriis Hmmmm.... I found my default __nicematrix__ is 2020/03/23 v3.14, and it doesn't recognize the package option ```Package keyvalue Error: Unknown option 'define-L-C-R' for package```  Is there any workround?

Comment: @吕和瑾: I thought you just updated your `nicematrix` package to version 5.12, now you claim to use version 3.14?

Comment: @leandriis Sorry for the confusion. I tried to update it to version 5.12, but failed, got 5.13, which seems to have bug in my environment. The default version in my local environment is 3.14, and the code (LCR capital letters) doesn't work in overleaf environment (It seems the version on overleaf is more than v5.0). What I want is to ensure the local environment and overleaf can successfully compile the same files. So I  got stuck by these problem.

Comment: Ummm, I got myself confused, I indeed updated to 5.12, but it doesn't work well, I thought it's a broken version and it cannot successfully compile. Not 5.13, sorry for confusion again. So, now I have local environment v3.14, but when it's updated to 5.12, it will not work, errors is like the above message. So I am seeking a way to update it to 5.11 or some workround to ensure both local 3.14 and overleaf to work smoothly.

Comment: @吕和瑾: Please prepare a MWE that allows others to reproduce the error messages you show in your question. Probably, there is just a simple syntax error in your file that can easily be fixed.

Comment: @leandriis Okay, thanks

Comment: The recent versions of `nicematrix` require recent versions of LaTeX. For example, v. 5.12 require LaTeX posterior to the version 2020/10/01.

Comment: @F.Pantigny So can I just update several packages via tlmgr to make it work?

Comment: @Rmano Could you plz reopen this question? I don't think it's solve yet.

Comment: On Overleaf, you have to upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive:
https:www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty

Answer (score 1):

I finally got a little more elegant solution to my problem from this [post](https://github.com/tuna/thuthesis/issues/623), and here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{nicematrix} 

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_set_true:N \c__nicematrix_define_L_C_R_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document} 
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbf{I}_{temp}=\begin{bNiceArray}{CCC@{\quad \quad}CCC@{\quad \quad}CCC@{\quad \quad}CCC}
    255 & 128 & 127 & 126 & 125 & 64 & 100 & 99 & 50 & 20 & 10 & 9  \\
  \end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I compiled it successfully in both local (v3.14) and overleaf (v5.0+) environments.
PS: still only capital letters, but it works for me

Also thanks to @leandriis and @F. Pantigny